# How to interpret this bode diagram

Tags: analysis, matlab, bode-plot

I have this bode diagram. I am wondering how to interpret this. We start off with 90 degree phase lag e.g. a integrator. Then at approx 12 Hz we drop another 180 degrees indicating two integrators.

Now my problem is with the ripples which start at about 60 Hz and continue to blow up till it reaches some maximum? and then it stops at 4KHz? What are these?

ps. it has to do with this question, [Derive transfer function from block diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98575/derive-transfer-function-from-block-diagram), for which I was able to derive the frequency response.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer only:

Check the period associated with the frequency of each notch in the frequency response. You will probably find they are integer multiples of the shortest period. This is typical of a "comb filter", often implemented as the sum of a signal and a delayed version of itself (the notch corresponds to delay=half a cycle). So look for a delay line in the block diagram.

Comment: Okay so that would proberbly be then the loop in the upper and lower right corner, from the image in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98575/derive-transfer-function-from-block-diagram?lq=1. I'm gonne check this.